# Dynamic Serving with Mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mobile

I put a `mod_rewrite` rule in `httpd.conf` to try to handle mobile requests.  If the browser on the sending device accepts mobile stuff, I want to rewrite the request to the original file name with an "m_" in front.  So if a mobile device sends:

```
https://example.com/51/a1.html
```

I want to rewrite it to

```
 https://example.com/51/m_a1.html
```

I have the lines below now in httpd.conf:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC]

RewriteRule ^example.com/([0-9]*)/(.*)$ ^example.com/$1/m_$2
```

But requests from a mobile device don't get rewritten. 
Does anyone see a problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your second line should be like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]*)/(.*)$ /$1/m_$2
```

And your first line doesn't need to escape slashes:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text/vnd\.wap\.wml|application/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC]
```

As for the validity of those `HTTP_ACCEPT` matches, I haven't checked them.